# making hash to produce JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, hash

I am creating a hash which would produce JSON to be used in APIs.

To make Hash I am trying this:

```
presses = Press.select(:id, :name)
pulls = Pull.select(:id, :name)
response = {list: {presses: presses, pulls: pulls}}
```

Actually works good and produces:

```
{"list":{
  "presses":[
     {"id":1,"name":"p40"},
     {"id":2,"name":"p41"}],

  "pulls":[
     {"id":1,"name":"Best Effort"},
     {"id":2,"name":"First Good"}]
}}
```

But the requirement has changed to make it like:

```
{"list":{
  "presses":[
     {"id":1,"name":"p40"
     "pulls":[
       {"id":1,"name":"Best Effort"},
       {"id":2,"name":"First Good"}]},

     {"id":2,"name":"p41"
     "pulls":[
       {"id":1,"name":"Best Effort"},
       {"id":2,"name":"First Good"}]},
     ],
}}
```

**Note** Each `press object` should contain all `pull object`. So far don't know how to achieve this. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is Rails question. Thus I have [`#attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes) method. Here is my attempt

```
presses = Press.select(:id, :name)
pulls = Pull.select(:id, :name)

response = { list: {
  presses: presses.map do |press|
    press.attributes.merge(pulls: pulls.map(&:attributes))
  end
}
}.to_json
```

Comment: too good man! I have many other attributes as well so I only selected few of them. And don;t need to_json because default format is json.

Comment: @G.B You just mark your post as Rails.. otherwise it is not valid answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want

```
pulls = Pull.select(:id, :name)
presses = Press.select(:id, :name)
presses = presses.collect do |press|
    press.merge({pulls: pulls})
end
response = {list: {presses: presses}}
```

Comment: No problem, if someone stumbles upon this though at least there is a version in pure ruby.